# $\overline{X} \rightarrow c$ in probability $\Rightarrow g(\overline{X}) \rightarrow g(c)$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Prove that if $\overline{X} \rightarrow c$ in probability and if **g is a continuous function**, then $g(\overline{X}) \rightarrow g(c)$ in probability.

Once I think in the situation $|g|<M$, it is quite easy to prove. But I don't know how to prove it in more general case.

Also for the bold words, how general can the function **g** be?

Comment: Here is a proof in a more general case where $c$ is not necessarily constant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Comment: @Augustin, Thank! But, is there a difference in this case? In this case, $c$ seems to be a number, but $X$ (on wiki) is a random variable. What should I do to deal with the difference between **a number** or **a random variable**?

Comment: You can always consider that a constant $c$ is a degenerate random variable with Dirac distribution $\delta_c$. So the proof is still valid.

Comment: @Augustin Wow, I am quite excited now. Both **degenerate random variable** & **Dirac distribution** $\delta_c$ is a thing I haven't heard until now. Let me check it out in wiki. 
Would you mind discribe it more detail?

Comment: The Dirac distribution is a probability measure defined by $\delta_c(A)=1$ if $c\in A$ and $0$ otherwise (with $A$ a measurable set). It implies that if a random variable is $\delta_c$-distributed, then $P(X=c)=1$. Simply said, $X=c$ almost surely.

Comment: So, I can directly "let a degenerate random variable $D_c$, with $\delta_c(D_c)=1$ for $D_c=c$, then substitutes $D_c$ to $c$ in the proof. Then, it is still valid?

Comment: Remove the $\delta_c(D_c)=1$ part. It doesn't make sense since $\delta_c$ is a measure and $D_c$ a random variable. You can just substitute $X$ by $c$ in the proof, it'll be correct.

Comment: But it doesn't solve the problem of mine. $P($random variable $-$ number$)=0$ or $1$, it seems not intuitional to substitute $X$ by $c$... :(

Comment: What does P(random variable − number) mean ? "random variable - number" is not an event.

Comment: @Augustin, Sorry for the comments. I figure it out. I misunderstood sth before... Thanks.